# Making use of a while loop in MS SQL server to display Customer information

Tags: sql-server

Good day, I am using a while loop in SQL server. I am also making use of the Northwind database, but as I am trying to run the code I am getting an error that is as follows:

> "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6. Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ALFKI' to data type int."

This is the code: (I used this link as a reference for the Northwind database https://simplesqltutorials.com/while-loop/. I am not sure if I typed it out incorrectly)

```
DECLARE @IDVal INT

SET @IDVal = 1

WHILE (@IDVal <=91)

BEGIN

    DECLARE @CustomerName VARCHAR(40)
    SELECT @CustomerName = CompanyName
    FROM Customers 
    WHERE CustomerID = @IDVal
    PRINT 'Name of Customer # ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @IDVal) + ': ' + @CustomerName
    SET @IDVal = @IDVal + 1
END
```

May you please assist me on how to work around this as it is my first time working on SQL server and I tried the CAST function but that did not work either or I most probably did not use it in the correct context. I also tried searching for something similar to my enquiry but had no luck. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you do this and not just select all the rows `SELECT CompanyName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) FROM ...`

Comment: First of all, forget that T-SQL even offers `WHILE`. Just don't use it, because any solution based on working row by row is going to be slower than set-based solutions. That tutorial should be outlawed and its author given a stern talking to. Looping through records and printing them is *not* something you need to do in SQL; that's what clients are for, who process your `SELECT` results. Second, actually take a look at what is *in* `Customers.CustomerID`, with special attention to the type. Just because a column is a number in a tutorial doesn't mean you get to assume it is in your data.

Comment: Agreed with @JeroenMostert you should probably find a better tutorial. *"The WHILE loop is one of the most basic tools you should know when you are first starting out with Microsoft SQL Server."* just no, absolutely not.

Comment: It would seem that the `Customers.CustomerID` column is not an `int` column but perhaps one of type `char`, `varchar`, `nchar` or `nvarchar`.

Comment: While loop also known as Row By Agonising Row (RBAR)

Comment: instead of using 'Name of Customer # ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @IDVal) + ': ' + @CustomerName use the concat function the + operator does implicit conversions